# Bootstrap Mega Menu with Yamm Center and make full width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Yamm 3 mega menu for bootstrap.

I am having problems making the the menu go full width right across the whole screen outside of the container, then having the menu options centered in the middle.

For example on the link below, click on the navigation on PICTURES > this is exactly what i want but for the white background to carry on across the full width of the screen:

http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

I would like to similar to the auto trader. co . uk website.

I cannot figure it out at all, hope one of you CSS ninjas can help me!

Here is an example of what i want:
http://jsfiddle.net/5G845/1/

Here is what i am getting > click on PICTURES. Using the same markup:
http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="sub-nav">
    nav sub menu here
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: please provide the code of what you have already tried and where you got stuck doing it...

Comment: ...by the way, if you apply the script properly, apparently any type of menu there has the white background stretching across the full menu, so without code or example of what is not working for you, not really sure what answer you expect...

Comment: it might only be me, but that just confused me even more... i'll leave it to others to answer...

Comment: on this link http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/ when you click on the nav at the top on PICTURES. The contents of this (the columns and images) i wanted centered within the container but i want the background of it running full width of the screen, similar to the fiddle i did? Is that any clearer? cheers

Comment: yep, it is clearer now, thanks...

Comment: lol awesome help thank you so much!!!! wish there were more helpful people like you on here! keep up the good work

Comment: well, if you'd make your question clearer to begin with, you might get more people's attention, most of them don't even bother asking you for clarification, so yes, indeed I helped, and you are welcome.

Comment: ...and have a look at my comment to the answer of @user2464339 who actually nailed it (just didn't explain it very well at first)...

Answer (score 0):

Since it is within the container of the page, you will need to remove the "max-width" from the container, doing that will allow the width of the drop-down to span across the page.

Comment: more specifically, if you remove `max-width` from the container, it will allow the width of the drop-down to span across the page... if you update your answer with this, i'll give you an upvote as i believe that's the solution ;)

Comment: i gave you my upvote, as promised... ;) not sure who'd downvote it without commenting...

Comment: the navbar is inside the container, if you remove the max-width, the entire navbar will be full width, but only the subnav should be full width